# Does Microsoft Exchange 2007 have a REST API?

Tags: rest, exchange-server-2007

I have the need to communicate with Microsoft Exchange 2007 and wondering if there is a RESTful API i can use to communicate? Previously i have attempted to connect with the managed API  (EWSJavaApi) however with no success. I'm also aware of the SOAP webservice exposed by exchange however would prefer the REST option if one exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sorry. In 2007 REST was not nearly as common as it is today. Maybe in the next version but probably not.

Comment: thanks stimms. One other question, do you know if the 1.1.3 version of the managed API supports exchange 2007? The release notest for 1.1.3 state that it can be used to communicate with Ex 2010 but does not mention 2007.